# Fetch all mobile numbers from file regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(0|91)?[7-9]\\d{9}(\\b|$)");
```

This is i'm using regular expression but i'm not able to get if mobile number is at starting of the line.Below is my file im getting the out put as of now is 
(I'm writing all mbile numbers in to ouput file);
917205435005 
but expected is 7873553408,917205435005

Input :

> 7873553408 Abstract classes may have some executable methods
>   methods left unimplemented. Interfaces 
>   contain no implementation code. An abstract
>   class can have non abstract 917205435005 methods. 
>   All methods 1234 of an interface are abstract.

Output : 917205435005

Expected output : 7873553408, 7873923408 ,917205435005

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("D://MyWork/Mobile.txt"); 
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 
while (bufferedReader.read() != -1) { 
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); 
    lineNum++; 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(0|91)?[7-9]\\d{9}(\\b|$)"); 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line); 
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("at line....:" + lineNum +
                           ".....found....." + matcher.group() + 
                           "...start..." + matcher.start() +
                           "..end..." + matcher.end());
    }
```

Comment: This is unclear, please details

Comment: Share the whole code you try

Comment: 7873553408 Abstract classes may have some executable methods methods left unimplemented. Interfaces contain no implementation code. An abstract class can have non abstract 917205435005 methods. All methods 1234 of an interface are abstract.

Comment: Your pattern seems to work, whar is the problem

Comment: this is my file i'm not able to get the mobile number which is the beginning of the each line in file.I;m getting if the mobiule number is some where in the middle

Comment: Share the code you used please, without no help can be provided

Comment: \FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("D://MyWork/Mobile.txt");
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
  while (bufferedReader.read() != -1) {
   String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
   lineNum++;
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(0|91)?[7-9]\\d{9}(\\b|$)");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

Comment: while (matcher.find()) {System.out.println("at line....:" + lineNum + ".....found....." + matcher.group() + "...start..."
      + matcher.start() + "..end..." + matcher.end());

Comment: Above is the code

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of the line is denoted with the caret:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(0|91)?[7-9]\\d{9}(\\b|$)");
```

Comment: I have tried Caret also if you use that i'm getting empty output

Comment: Then it might depends on what you further do with your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To collect all the numbers, you need to make a `Matcher` and a `while-loop` to get all matches :

```
String str = "7873553408 Abstract classes may have some executable methods 7873923408 methods left unimplemented." +
            " Interfaces contain no implementation code. An abstract class can have non abstract 917205435005 methods." +
            " All methods 1234 of an interface are abstract.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(0|91)?[7-9]\\d{9}");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);

List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    phones.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(phones); //[7873553408, 7873923408, 917205435005]
```

- the pattern you write does not care of beginning/middle (if you had put a `^` you would have obtain only the one at beginning)
- You don't need `(\\b|$)` at the end of the pattern
- use this instead of `while (bufferedReader.read() != -1)` which consumes a `char` :

  ```
  String line;
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  ```

Comment: @John try with the change on the first while (see edit)

Comment: Thanks..it is woking

Comment: @John so you may think about accept/vote up answers that were useful, to thank the people who spend time for yor you ;)

Comment: Sure ...And info:how did this strike in your mind about read() and readLine()?

Comment: @John another answer make me think about, so I tried to check it

Answer (score 0):

I am thoroughly confused.  Currently, your question has two regular expressions: One with an anchor (`^`) and one without.  And you have two lists of expected output:  a list with two numbers, and a list with three numbers (one of which does not appear in your input file).

However, the most likely reason for your problem is this:

```
while (bufferedReader.read() != -1) {
```

bufferedReader.read() *consumes a character,* which means it will not be present in the String returned by the subsequent call to `bufferedReader.readLine()`.  Which means, the line you have read starts with `873553408 Abstract classes` (no leading ‘7’!), which your regular expression will not match.

Do not call read().  The correct way to loop through all lines returned by a BufferedReader is by checking whether readLine() returns null:

```
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex

```
\b(0?91)?(?:\s*-\s*|\s+)?(\d{3})(?:\s*-\s*|\s+)?(\d{3})(?:\s*-\s*|\s+)?(\d{4})\b
```

in which I supposed that your international code is `091`, domestic telephone number format is `3 digits-3 digits-4 digits`, for example, 091 333 444 5555, 091 - 333 - 444 - 5555, 0913334445555, 333 444 5555, 333 - 444 - 5555 etc ...

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/42)